# Action Method was not found on Controller - MVC Sitemap Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, methods, action, sitemap

My project was built with MVC3 Razor. And, recently I applied Ssl and Sitemap (mvcsitemap) regulation on this project. Then, last two days I get exception like these. But, these pages or method does not take part in my project. (Also, there is no such word). I think that is because from sitemap. But, I'm not sure. Why can be caused these errors?

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'dummy.aspx' was not found on controller 'Test.Controllers.HomeController'......
>
> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'cgi-bin' was not found on controller 'Test.Controllers.HomeController'......

thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you finding out about these exceptions? Are they coming via emails when visitors get site errors, or something similar? It could be users typing in URLs like '/cgi-bin' or '/Dummy.aspx'

Comment: Project are compiling smoothly. But, When I deploy to the project for publication, throws error. I get this exception in global.asax.cs (Application_Error method). Otherwise, I can not catch. Also, how this error is falling, I have no idea.

Comment: So you get these errors as soon as you deploy? Without anyone visiting the website at all?

Comment: As the fact that, after visiting errors coming

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: There is nothing in MvcSiteMapProvider that specifies these controllers or paths. I suspect there may be a problem with your route configuration and/or area configuration (if you are using areas). Could you post them?